# UpdateView without a PK or Slug

Tags: django, django-views

Having trouble with an UpdateView. I've tried over writing the get_object but I am getting

```
AttributeError at /companydata/update/
'User' object has no attribute 'get_companydata'
```

The CompanyData Model has a OneToOne relationship with User.

Here's my code:

urls.py

```
### Omitted ###
url(r'^update/$', CompanyDataUpdateView.as_view(),
    name='companydataupdate')
### Omitted ###
```

views.py

```
class CompanyDataUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = CompanyData
    fields = ['arr', 'num_cust']
    template_name = 'company_data/companydata_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.get_companydata()
```

models.py

```
class CompanyData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    arr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    num_cust = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('companyrevenue')
```

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` object has no method called `get_companydata`, hence your error. You need to access the reverse one-to-one relationship like so:

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user.companydata
```

Where `companydata` is a property, not a method (i.e., don't call it with brackets). This is the default reverse name for the [one-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield):

> If you do not specify the `related_name` argument for the `OneToOneField`, Django will use the lower-case name of the current model as default value.

If you want to be more explicit or use another name, then set the `related_name` on your `OneToOneField`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly and the time you spent explaining the reasoning behind the answer has helped me understand a bit more about related_name and methods vs. properties.